# Что означают числа в "embedding" векторе слов?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, векторы, word2vec

Допустим есть "embedding" вектор слова Арбуз = [-0.0415, -0.0079, -0.0261, ... 0.1022]. Что означают числа в этом векторе, как они получаются? Это какое-то отношение кол-ва раз, сколько в i-м тексте встретилось слово арбуз к количеству слов в этом тексте, или что это?
Пролистал уже много на русском и на английском. Видел примеры с King-Queen и т.д. Понимаю, что означают готовые векторы и как производится сравнение. Однако нигде не нашел именно этой информации. Интересует именно, как получают данные числа!

Comment: О каком векторе идет речь - "embedding vector" / TFIDF / что-то еще?

Comment: Что такое "вектор слова"?

Comment: Да, embedding vector. Надо было указать, что используется библиотека word2vec python, просто собирался указать в тегах, но из-за репутации оказалось нельзя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Word embedding vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) состоит из чисел характеризующих силу признаков, автоматически подсчитанных из лингвистического контекста. Список самых сильных признаков, таких как, например:

- пол
- возрастная категория
- фрукт/не фрукт
- жидкий/не жидкий
- и т.д.

выбирается из всех подсчитанных признаков. Обычно при подсчете "word embedding matrix" задается число самых сильных признаков, которые должны входить в результирующую матрицу, [например: `GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation` подсчитана для: 50d, 100d, 200d, 300d признаков](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Названия признаков в человеческом понимании в "word embedding matrix" нет, но их можно оценить используя готовую/расчитанную матрицу.

Например если взять индекс столбца с максимальными значениями для слов: `King` и `Queen`, то этот столбец будет обозначать характеристику описывающую принадлежность к королевским кровям и т.д.

PS ["An Intuitive Understanding of Word Embeddings: From Count Vectors to Word2Vec"](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/) - неплохая статья на английском с пояснением того, как расчитываются "Word Embeddings"

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!